# Произношение слова «случай» - это принцип или исключение?

Tags: произношение

Произношение слова «случай» звучит как «случий». Если я бы знал как его написать, я бы написал «случий» или «случьяй», потому что знаю, что безударное «я» звучит как «и». Но безударное «а» звучит как «а», и так не понимаю почему в слове «случай» иначе. Есть какой-то принцип про это или это исключение?

Comment: а что происходит с вами, когда вы на слух воспринимаете слово "обычай",  например? )

Comment: @shabunc Я бы написал <<обычи(й)>> :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Да, это закономерно: после мягких согласных звуков в слабой позиции звук [а] редуцируется до [и]: **счастливый, сякой, язык.** (Слово **язык** начинается с мягкого согласного [й].)

Поэтому, например, слова **чистота** и **частота** звучат одинаково.

Есть даже анекдот:

```
Мама: Доча, чем вас сегодня кормили в садике?
Дочь: Чем-то на букву И!
Мама: Икра?
Дочь: Не-е-ет!
Мама: Изюм?
Дочь: Не-е-ет!
Мама: Что же это?
Дочь: Иичко!
```

Comment: Никогда не обращала внимания, интересно.

Comment: Надо сказать, что произношение еще может зависеть от акцента :) Где нибудь под Вологдой скажут случАй, а на Юге России  чаще услышишь "случИй". Акценты вообще интересная штука у носителей русского языка.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте прочитать «случй» или «случьй». У вас получится примерно то же самое. Это и есть редукция — вы стараетесь произнести как можно меньше гласного в данной позиции.

В слове «молоко», например, в первом слоге тоже не [а] произносится (в «стандартном» произношении), так что дело не только в мягкости.